# How to Optimise the following algorithm? maximum good value of an element in an array

Tags: algorithms, optimization, number-theory

I was recently stuck while doing a question, please suggest a way with a code/pseudo code to optimize the following algorithm for finding the maximum good value in an array where a good value of an array element $A_i$ is defined as the total no. of Valid indices $<$ such that $_$ is divisible by $_$. My approach is as follows,

```
    int maximum=-1;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(arr[j]%arr[i]==0)
            count++;
        }
        maximum=max(count,maximum);
     }
     print(maximum);
```

Comment: @Juho I want to Optimise my algorithm such that I can solve it in less than a 1 sec for the constraints, $$1≤T≤10$$ $$1≤arraysize≤10^5$$ $$1≤A_i≤10^6$$

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the input values the following strategy might work:
keep an array $C$ of $10^6$ elements where $C[i]$ will store the number of times number $i$ appears in the elements of the input array that have already been processed.

Initially $C$ is identically 0, then you consider the elements $A_i$ one at a time. When you are processing the $A_i$ you can compute the "good value" by taking the sum of all $C[k A_i]$ for $k=1,\dots,\lfloor 10^6 / A_i \rfloor$. Then, increment $C[A_i]$.

At the end of the process return the maximum sum.

A more refined strategy is that of handling separately small and large values of $A_i$. If $A_i \ge 1000$ then the above algorithm check at most $10^3$ entries in $C$. 
If $A_i < 1000$ then you can find the number of its multiples by checking and keeping track of how many of the input elements seen so far are divisible by the numbers between $1$ and $1000$. This also requires $\approx 1000$ operations. So you'll be performing $\approx 2 \cdot 10^5 \cdot 10^3$ operations as opposed to $10^{10}$ of your algorithm.

An even better strategy is to keep an array $D$ where $D[n]=j$ means that  $j$ of the numbers seen so far have $n$ a divisor. Since the number of divisors grows slowly (as $O(\log n / \log \log n)$, and it is always at most $240$ for your values) this strategy will only increment a few values per input number (less than 14 on average, assuming an uniform input distribution. See [here](https://oeis.org/A000005/graph) for a plot of the number of divisors of the first $10^5$ integers).
The leaves you with a number of operations of the order of $10^6$ to $10^7$.

The problem is now that of enumerating, for each number $n$, its divisors efficiently. But you can just do this as a preprocessing step by multiplying each $i=1,\dots,10^6$ by consecutive integers $k$ until it exceeds $10^6$. For each such $k$ add  $i$ to the list of divisors of $k \cdot i$. This could even be done once-for-all and hardcoded in your algorithm.

Comment: The method is somewhat difficult to understand, can you post a pseudo code or code for this so that I can understand it easily?

Comment: Something along [these lines](https://pastebin.com/AgpBBg9X). In the code `divisors` is an array containing all the divisors of $1$, followed by all the divisors (in increasing onder) of $2$, ..., up to all the divisors of $10^6$, and $ndiv[i] = \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} d(j)$, where $d(j)$ is the number of divisors of $j$.